# Emacs commands in xterm

Tags: bash, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

I found that the commands I used to use in `gnome-terminal`, those I learned in Emacs, are only partially working in `xterm`. In some cases, I get strange chars like `ÿ`, `æ`, and `â` instead. Do you know how to enable the shortcuts (or even setting them up one by one, as they are not that many)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put

```
xterm*metaSendsEscape: true
```

in your `~/.Xresources` file.

Comment: I had to put `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources &` in `.xinitrc` because I don't have a desktop environment. But it works, thanks!

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Drop the `&`. `xrdb` returns as soon as it's done its job. With the `&`, the programs you start in your `.xinitrc` or very very soon after you've logged in won't have all resources set yet.