# How to change readline's/bash's meta key?

Tags: bash, terminal, readline

Readline/bash use the meta key quite often but it only works when I use the Esc-key for it.
How can I configure bash/readline to accept a different key as meta?

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with the shell, but rather the terminal emulator. What terminal emulator are you using? (urxvt, gnome-terminal, etc)

Comment: I use xterm and screen.

Answer (score 5):

This is the same question I asked I while back, so I'm not taking credit for this, but I had to put

```
xterm*metaSendsEscape: true
URxvt*altSendsEscape: true
```

in `.Xresources` to make <kbd>Alt</kbd> work as Meta in both xterm and urxvt. It is a bit contradictory, but it works. So experiment with those options. Also, I had to put

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

in `.xinitrc` for it to work.

**Edit:** My question: [Emacs commands in xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/emacs-commands-in-xterm)